# Can't install Visual Code on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, visual-studio-code

I recently installed Ubuntu and I am new to it. Now I wanted to program with Visual Code but the problem is I can't download it. I tried `sudo apt install ./<file>.deb` (with my file path of course) but I only get this Error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 code:amd64 : Depends: libnss3:amd64 (>= 2:3.26) but it is not installable
              Depends: apt:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libxkbfile1:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libsecret-1-0:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgtk-3-0:amd64 (>= 3.10.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: libxss1:amd64 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgbm1:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also had a lot of problems with installing anything including changing the keyboards layout.

I'm on a M1 MacBook and using Parallels Desktop.

Output of sudo apt update:

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease            
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease             
Reading package lists... Done                           
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Output of sudo apt -f install:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

No output for dpkg --get-selections | grep hold

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Related: [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you [edit] to include your Ubuntu version? Also, include the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt -f install`.  You may also include the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M1 is ARM, so you can't install amd64 packages here.

But you can try installing VSCodium for ARM from https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/releases using one of the following commands (depending on CPU arch):

```
cd ~/Downloads
# 32-bit
wget -c https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/releases/download/1.63.2/codium_1.63.2-1639700511_armhf.deb
sudo apt-get install ./codium_1.63.2-1639700511_armhf.deb

# 64-bit
wget -c https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/releases/download/1.63.2/codium_1.63.2-1639700587_arm64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./codium_1.63.2-1639700587_arm64.deb
```